# Is it true that sequence of non negative reals converging to one can not have initial term zero

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \geq0}$ of real numbers in [0,1] converging to one.
Then is it true that $x_1 >0$.

Comment: Sorry I missed [0,1] and limit one

Comment: If the sequence converges to $1$, any finite number of terms of the sequence could be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define $(x_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ in the following way:

If $n=0$, then $x_{0}:=0$.

If $n=1$, then $x_{1}:=0$.

If $n\geq 2$, then $x_{n}:=1-\frac{1}{n}$.

It means $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty}x_{n}=1$ but $x_{1}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "a sequence ... of positive real numbers", that means that $x_1$ is positive, and $x_2$ is positive, and $x_3$ is positive, etc. To say $x_1$ is positive is equivalent to writing $x_1>0$.

---

To the edited question: Let $x_1=0$ and $x_n=1$ for all $n\neq1$.

Comment: The question has been edited :)

Comment: @Daniel Ah, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence given by$$x_1 = 0$$ $$x_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}, n\geq1 $$

Comment: but limit is zero.

Comment: Sorry misread the question, it has been fixed